# Spyder debugger freezes within Anaconda virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, anaconda, spyder

I'm working with an Anaconda virtual environment, `venv`, and I'm running Spyder from it.

Whenever I attempt debugging my code, nothing happens. The debugger seems to get stuck in the first line. For example, if I run the debugger on:

```py
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

Running in debug mode produces this output on the built-in IPython console:

```py
debugfile('C:/Projects/Myproject/myscript.py', wdir='C:/Projects/Myproject')
> c:\projects\myproject\myscript.py(1)<module>()
----> 1 import sys
      2 
      3 print(sys.executable)
```

Neither Debugging buttons in Spyder, nor their related shortcuts, seem to do anything. In particular, pressing the Stop button (or hitting CTRL+SHIFT+F12) results in:

```py
--KeyboardInterrupt--
For copying text while debugging, use Ctrl+Shift+C
```

I have already made some research, and landed on this [GitHub issue page](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4214), where it is suggested that I should update IPython. I did, with no benefit.

Another suggestion I found in this [other GitHub page](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#the-modular-approach) indicated the problem might be that the wrong executable for Python is run (i.e., that Spyder is running Python from my base Anaconda environment, rather than my `venv`). I checked, and both are run from the right path:

```py
print(sys.executable)

C:\Anaconda3\envs\venv\python.exe
```

These are the version of my dependencies.

```py
Spyder version: 5.1.5 None
Python version: 3.7.11 64-bit
Qt version: 5.9.7
PyQt5 version: 5.9.2
IPython 7.31.1
Operating System: Windows 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I face the same issue, Spyder 5.1.5 debugging does not work in new environments. There is some clash between versions as I understand, but promised that they will deal with the issue in the next version.

Also, this is a reported issues: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17350

What seems to work for me is to create a new environment but specify the versions like this:

```
conda create -n your_fancy_env_name -c conda-forge python=3.8.10 spyder=5.1.5
```